# Selenium web driver assert webelement contains text and display actual vs expected

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng, assert

I have a demo selenium cucumber project that just runs some maths expressions in google search box and validates the results.

I want the reports to show the actual value vs expected when it fails.

I'm storing the returned text as string with ..

```
String resultText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='dDoNo vrBOv vk_bk']")).getText();
```

and then asserting against expected which gets passed from my feature files with ...

```
assertTrue(resultText.equals(expectedResult));
```

but the reports show ...

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]
```

I want it to display the actual expected result vs actual i.e.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [200] but found [201]
```

I've also tried ...

```
Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult, resultText);
```

I'm using ... org.testng.Assert

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assertion you can use your customized error text. Something like this:

```java
Assert.assertEquals(resultText, expectedResult, "Expected: " + expectedResult + " but found " + resultText);
```

Or this

```java
Assert.assertTrue(expectedResult.equals(resultText), "Expected: " + expectedResult + " but found " + resultText);
```

In case of non-equal parameters it will present you output like this for the first case:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Expected: expectedResult but found resultText
> Expected :expectedResult
> Actual   :resultText

And for the second case:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Expected: expectedResult but found resultText
> Expected :true
> Actual   :false

Comment: Thanks so this is what I'm getting back with the first one... 125 expected:<[129]> but was:<[Expected: 129 but found 125.]>.

Comment: I just tried it without the message text i.e. Assert.assertEquals(resultText, expectedResult); and I get ...expected:<12[5]> but was:<12[9]> which is good enough. Thanks.